# How can I declare a var inside an if statement

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to declare the same variable `item` with different types depending of the type of a generic variable `itemBase`.

`itemBase` can be of either type `DebtorOrder` or `DebtorOffer`. Those are almost identical so in the later code they can be handled the same way.

```cs
async void UnfoldBOM<T>(T itemBase)
{
    if (itemBase.GetType() == typeof(DebtorOrder))
    {
        DebtorOrder item = itemBase as DebtorOrder;
    }
    else
    {
        DebtorOffer item = itemBase as DebtorOffer;
    }
}
```

This is giving me "The name 'item' does not exist in current context".

I do understand why that is, but how can I do this without giving the vars different names and declaring them before the `if` statement?

DebtorOrder and DebtorOffer both have the parameter price, so I would be able to do

```
var price = item.price
```

inside the if statement, but if I do the same after the if statement I get T does not contain definition for price.

Why doesn't that work when using the generic type?

Comment: When you declare a variable in a block, it's only valid inside the scope of that block. So your `item` won't be valid outside of your `if` or `else` body ...

Comment: "...in the later code they can be handled the same way" If that is the case, then the latter code should be able to do what it needs to do by accessing `itemBase` directly.

Comment: Your inheritance feels messed up.   In most cases, you shouldn't need to know child types, just act on it accordingly to the abilities provided by the base item.  If your generic is that specific, it's not generic.

Comment: " almost identical " is not enough for polymorphism. There needs to be a common base type or interface. If they have common properties then you could create an interface with those properties that they both implement. Then your code will work against that interface rather than the types themselves.

Comment: What is the point of your casts?  You have a function that takes an `itemBase` of type `T` (by the way, is `T` constrained to be a common supertype of `DebtorOffer` and `DebtorOrder` - if not, you are probably doomed here).  Then it tries to cast things, then it returns with no side effects. C# does not have structural typing, it relies on inheritance  (and co- and contra-variance).  Just because both types have a `.price` member doesn't allow you to do what you want.  You need to make a common `IHaveAPriceMember` interface that they both extend (or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to create a variable `item` that will obtain different value depending on type of variable `itemBase`. If yes, then you can do following steps:

1. Create a parent class or interface
2. DebtorOrder and DebtorOffer should be inherited from this class/interface
3. Before if-statement declare a variable of type this parent class/interface
4. Assign your value inside an if-statement with previously casting it to particular type

Some sample of code:

```
using System;

interface IDebtor{
    void Print();
}

public class DebtorOrder: IDebtor{
    public void Print(){
        Console.WriteLine("DebtorOrder");
    }
}

public class DebtorOffer: IDebtor{
   public void Print(){
        Console.WriteLine("DebtorOffer");
    } 
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDebtor itemBase = new DebtorOrder();
        IDebtor item = null;
        
        if (itemBase.GetType() == typeof(DebtorOrder))
        {
            item = itemBase as DebtorOrder;
        }
        else
        {
            item = itemBase as DebtorOffer;
        }
        
        item.Print();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that would work, but I do not control the two types DebtorOrder and DebtorOffer, so I can't make then enherit from an interface. They come from a nuget.

Comment: Without a common base class or interface, then you can only do this with Reflection.  You'll need to create `MethodInfo`s that can be invoked on either class to extract the `.price` members.  Don't reflect each time looking for the `.price` members, do it once and  cache the results.

Answer (score -1):

C# doesn't have structural typing, so you have to do it yourself, using Reflection.  Consider this class:

```
public class CommonPropertyReflector<TProperty> 
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _propertyGetters;

    public CommonPropertyReflector(string propertyName)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _propertyGetters = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
    }

    public void AddType (Type type)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(_propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type: {type.Name} does not have a {_propertyName} property");
        }
        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(TProperty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type of {type.Name}.{_propertyName} must be {typeof(TProperty).Name}");
        }
        var propertyGetter = property.GetGetMethod();
        if (propertyGetter == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{type.Name}.{_propertyName} must be a readable property");
        }

        _propertyGetters.Add(type, propertyGetter);
    }   

    public TProperty? GetPropertyValue(object value)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (!_propertyGetters.TryGetValue(type, out var propertyGetter))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Value: [{value}] is not a registered type");
        }
        return (TProperty?) propertyGetter.Invoke(value, null);
    }
}
```

I need two dummy classes:

```
public class DebtorOrder
{
    public string? OrderStuff { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class DebtorOffer
{
    public string? OfferStuff { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I can then rewrite your `UnfoldBOM` method as:

```
public static decimal UnfoldBOM<T>(T itemBase, CommonPropertyReflector<decimal> reflector)
{
    if (itemBase is DebtorOffer offer)
    {
        return reflector.GetPropertyValue(offer);
    }
    else if (itemBase is DebtorOrder order)
    { 
        return reflector.GetPropertyValue(order);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("you are on your own here");
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
var priceReflector = new CommonPropertyReflector<decimal>("Price");
priceReflector.AddType(typeof(DebtorOffer));
priceReflector.AddType(typeof(DebtorOrder));

var order = new DebtorOrder() { OrderStuff = "Order", Price = 100.101m };
var offer = new DebtorOffer() { OfferStuff = "Offer", Price = 200.234m };

var orderPrice = UnfoldBOM(order, priceReflector);
var offerPrice = UnfoldBOM(offer, priceReflector);

Debug.WriteLine($"OrderPrice: {orderPrice}");
Debug.WriteLine($"OfferPrice: {offerPrice}");
```

The output looks like:

```
OrderPrice: 100.101
OfferPrice: 200.234
```

By the way, if you are going to do this a lot, I suggest that you cache the `CommonPropertyReflector` instance.  It reflects over two types looking for a property of the right name, so it's expensive.  It's immutable, so you can call it over and over on any thread once it's constructed.

**UPDATE**  *(after comment from OP  (2023-03-30)*

Unlike TypeScript, C# doesn't support *structural typing*.  What I'm saying is that just because two types (/classes or structs) have similar property (or other member) names and types doesn't mean that the two types have and relationship within C#.

As a result (answering your original question), you *cannot* do what you were trying to do in the example you showed in your original post.  No one really answered your question since there is no real way to do what you asked.

This answer was one way around those constraints.  It allows you to read property values from two unrelated types in a bit of a roundabout way.  It's not really that complicated, it's really just the `CommonPropertyReflector` class.

If you don't want to do this, the only way you will achieve your goal is to have your two types (`DebtorOrder` and `DebtorOffer`) implement a common interface (you could do it with a class or abstract class as well, but an interface is probably the simplest solution).  Somewhere, in the last 5 years I worked on a system that had a ton of these (remember, a class can implement more than one interface).  So, something like:

```
public interface ISupportPrice 
{
    public decimal Price { get; }
}
```

And then declare both `DebtorOrder` and `DebtorOffer` to implement `ISupportPrice`.  You may want to make the `Price` property read/write on the interface, but you may find that read-only is good enough.

Comment: Good try. The code I'm trying not to replace is 80 lines, so it make no sense to add all this complexity. I give up

Comment: Please edit your answer and I'll undo the second downvote. It was by mistake, but I can't reverse.